# HTML: ordered sublists

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to create a ordered html list like this:

1.0 Introduction

1.1 Features

1.2 Readme

1.3 Thanks

...

How do I do this with html?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number nested ordered lists in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter's are the way to go. [See this fiddle which goes three levels deep](http://jsfiddle.net/WqXFK/12/.).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the CSS `counter-increment` (and possibly the `counter-reset`) property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp

Comment: Hi,

I have a lot of sub lists. This would be very chaotic with resetting everything via css.

Are there some nices solutions?

Comment: You can attach a CSS class to each item in the list and sub-list (see this example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_gen_counter-reset).  I'm not exactly sure what qualifies as a "nicer" solution as now I'm not sure of the ultimate task you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi,

If I have this structure:


<ol>
 <li>
  <ol>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
<ol>

What do I have to do. I don't understand the reference
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered here

[Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)

The following style sheet numbers nested list items as "1", "1.1", "1.1.1", etc.

```
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

Maybe you can edit your question to avoid duplicating questions. Pointing to that one I just told you.