# HTML: How to create a numerated index

Tags: html, css, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number nested ordered lists in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html)
>   [HTML: ordered sublists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930732/html-ordered-sublists)

I want to create a numerated Index:

1.0

1.1

1.1.1

1.1.2

1.1.3

1.2

2.0

2.1

2.2

What is the best way to do this?
ul, ol?

```
<ul>
<li><span>1.0</<span>First entry</li>
<li><span>1.1</<span>Second entry</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Go look at your original question you posted a bit earlier. I answered that.

Comment: @ScottS: what makes you think it's the same user behind both questions? They're very simmilar, yes; but that might just be coincidence.

Comment: @DavidThomas--because it is the same user number (user1246987) :-)

Comment: Hi,

it's not really a duplicate :)

Thank you for the solution ScottS but I decided to keep the index static and to keep the index static I would like to know whats the best solution to set the numeration self?

Comment: If you are going to do it static, then what is there to "set the numeration" other than you typing it in (anything else would not be static)? I guess the question is, if it is static, you already have that, so what then is your real question?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is easily made with css per counter-increment. You don't need to write the numbers yourself anymore.

Read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do it i give you example

**css**

```
body{
    counter-reset:section;
}
div{
    margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;
}
.numercal {
    counter-reset:subsection;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.numercal:before{
    counter-increment:section;
    content:"Section " counter(section) ". ";
    font-style:italic;
    color:red;
}
.numercal-no:before{
    counter-increment:subsection;
    content:counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p class="numercal">Demo Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
</div>


<div>
    <p class="numercal">Demo Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
</div>




<div>
    <p class="numercal">Demo Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
    <p class="numercal-no">Sub Text here</p>
</div>
​
```

Live demo [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Xwm3C/1/) http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Xwm3C/1/

Now more about this go to this site http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/counter-increment

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/counter-increment

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the spans unless you explisitly want to mark it up as something, for styling etc...
What you have done seams fine unless you need it to do something different from what it does now.
If you just want it enumerated with 1, 2, 3, etc then you can use ol instead of ul.

Comment: <ul>
     <li><span>1.0</<span>First entry</li>
     <li><span>1.1</<span>Second entry</li>
     <li><span>1.2</<span>Second entry</li>
    </ul>

Hi, yes I would like to use the spans to set styling equal to a default ol list.

I chose to use the static solution because the dynamic isn't cosher in my eyes :(