# ordered list - loop numbers in sub-menus

Tags: html, css

I have ordered list:

### HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item
        <ol>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
<ol>
```

### Output:

```
1. Item
2. Item
    1. Item
    2. Item
3. Item
4. Item
```

### Quesion:

**How apply counting for sub-levels ?**

*Note: looking for simple solution CSS/HTML*

Wanted output:

```
1. Item
2. Item
    2.1. Item
    2.2. Item
3. Item
4. Item
```

Comment: Possible duplicat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930732/html-ordered-sublists

Comment: have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp

Comment: Why would it be `1.1` and not `2.1` ?

Comment: @gvee thx, I fixed it in original post, my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item;
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")". ";
    counter-increment: item
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Superb answer. Its since CSS2 :)