# What is the correct way to number a list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number nested ordered lists in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html)

Apologies as I'm a bit of a css noob.

I have a list of terms and conditions.

The each section is numbered like this:

```
1.0 This Website
1.1 This website...
1.2 etc etc

2.0 ...
2.1 ...
2.2 ...
```

I know I can use an ordered list, but as I understand it the 'start' property is depreciated.

What alternatives have I got?

Comment: **start** was reintroduced in html5, so you can use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/ol

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-type) css property.

```
ol { list-style-type: decimal; }
```

Comment: This is the default setting, and it generates simple numbering 1, 2, 3 etc., not numbering like “1.0”.

Answer (score 2):

Stealing from [Mozilla - Using CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Counters)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yV43N/1/)

HTML:

```
<ol class="level0">
  <li>This Website
    <ol>
      <li>This website</li>
      <li>etc etc</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>...
    <ol>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol.level0 > li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") ".0 ";
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **counter-increment** for this. Write like this:
**HTML**

```
<ol>
  <li>item 1
    <ol>
      <li>sub item 1</li>
      <li>Sub item 2</li>
   </ol>
  </li>
  <li>item 2
    <ol>
      <li>sub item 1</li>
      <li>Sub item 2</li>
   </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}     
ol li { counter-increment: section; }

ol li:before  { content: counters(section, ".") ". "; }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/xC8ne/10/

Check this for more [Number nested ordered lists in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html)