# HTML ordered list indent to keep original numbering

Tags: html, list

I need to indent an ordered list to keep the parent list items numbering:

What I have:

```
 // My code:
 <ol>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>
           Item 2
           <ol>
                <li>Item 2.1</li>
                <li>Item 2.2</li>
           </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
 </ol>
```

And so forth.

What i'm getting as a result now is:

```
      // Result:
      1. Item 1
      2. Item 2
           Item 1
           Item 2
      3. Item 3
```

What i'm looking for is:

```
      // Looking for:
      1. Item 1
      2. Item 2
           2.1 Item 2.1
           2.2. Item 2.2
      3. Item 3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number nested ordered lists in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#counter) to do so:

```
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by DON's answer, I played around with the counters property and managed to get the following working:

```
 ol {
     counter-reset: item;
     list-style-type: none;
 }

 ol li:before {
     font-weight: bold;
     content: counters(item,".")".   "; 
     counter-increment: item;
 }

 ol ol {
     counter-reset: subitem;
     list-style-type: none;
 }

 li li:before {
     content: counters(item,".")"."counters(subitem,".")".   "; 
     counter-increment: subitem;
 }
```

I'm not convinced that this is the most clean cut solution because I don't know the content element that well but this will definately give you an ordered list which incremints sub level list items according to their parent containers last list item.