# Styling indent with HTML or CSS like in Ms Word

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I need a help to get `a., b.` style inner indent instead of `2.2.1., 2.2.2.`. Found the original CSS code from [HTML ordered list indent to keep original numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577782/html-ordered-list-indent-to-keep-original-numbering)

**My code:**

```
<style>
    ol { counter-reset: item }
    li { display: block }
    li:before { content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item }
</style>

<ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>
        Two
        <ol>
            <li>Two one</li>
            <li>
                Two two
                <ol type="a">
                    <li>Two two a</li>
                    <li>Two two b</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Two three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

**What I'm getting:**

```
1. One
2. Two
   2.1. Two one
   2.2. Two two
      2.2.1. Two two a
      2.2.2. Two two b
   2.3. Two three
3. Three
```

**What I need:**

```
1. One
2. Two
   2.1. Two one
   2.2. Two two
      a. Two two a
      b. Two two b
   2.3. Two three
3. Three
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't need to prepend the inner lists with the section numbering, you can add an additional rule using `counter` to get the letters:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")". ";
    counter-increment: item
}
ol ol ol li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha)". ";
}
```

Details: http://jsfiddle.net/kmAJ6/3/. Should work with your existing HTML.

Comment: Without extra element attribute and indent for a, b .. is in same length as numbers. Thanks

Comment: This is a smart solution, looks like I'll have to read up something about counters..

Comment: @MightyPork thanks! Honestly, I learned a bit about counters for this one. I just wish there was a more programmatic way to do it, instead of targeting specific list levels.

Answer (score 1):

Your `type` attribute has no effect because your css replaces the default numbering.  One way around this would be to update your css rules to only target the first 2 levels and let the 3rd level use the default numbering.  This will then let your `type` attribute take effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/TbjcV/

```
.level1,
.level2{ 
    counter-reset: item 
}

.level1 > li,
.level2 > li{ 
    display: block 
}
.level1 > li:before,
.level2 > li:before{ 
    content: counters(item, ".") ". "; 
    counter-increment: item 
}
```

```
<ol class="level1">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>
        Two
        <ol class="level2">
            <li>Two one</li>
            <li>
                Two two
                <ol type="a" class="level3">
                    <li type="a">Two two a</li>
                    <li>Two two b</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Two three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this:

```
<style>
ol.cnt { counter-reset: item }
ol.cnt > li { display: block }
ol.cnt > li:before { content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item }
</style>
```

html:

```
<ol class="cnt">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>
        Two
        <ol class="cnt">
            <li>Two one</li>
            <li>
                Two two

                <ol type="a">
                    <li>Two two a</li>
                    <li>Two two b</li>
                </ol>

            </li>
            <li>Two three</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

a bit messy, but seems to work.

Comment: I think it is tidy! Thanks.