# Ordered list in special format

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was looking for a smart way to create a nested ordered list with a particular format:

```
1. text
2. text
 2.1 text
 2.2 text
 2.3 text
3. text
4. text
 4.1 text
 4.2 text
 4.3 text
5. text
```

I was trying to use the type atrib in there, but it didn't got me anywhere.
I don't need the indentation....but that would be nice...

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish. Is this static HTML? Where is the text coming from? What have you tried?

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html

Comment: dudes, how can I make the numbers bold???

Answer (score 4):

Use [counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#counter) for that

```
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

Comment: OSOM! simple awesome dude :D, now I Have just a litle problem... the first element just shows "1" the nested ones works beautifully, but I would want that the first elem also shows the dot: "1."

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more of the actual HTML. You can accomplish this kind of numbering (subclauses) with CSS.

```
ol.main > li {
   counter-increment: root;
}

ol.main > li > ol {
    counter-reset: subsection;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol.main > li > ol > li {
    counter-increment: subsection;
}

ol.main > li > ol > li:before {
    content: counter(root) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```