# Is there a way to create multi-level lists like these using HTML5 and CSS only?

Tags: css, html

I would like to create lists like these using **HTML5** and **CSS** only:

```
1 First
  1.1 Indent 1
  1.2 Indent 2
2 Second
  2.1 Indent 1
  2.2 Indent 2
    2.2.1 More depth
```

I've checked multiple tutorials on ordered lists but it seems that the `<ol>` tag does not have the option to do so. Is it possible using **HTML5** and **CSS**?

Comment: Is the automatic numbering of those list what your question is actually about? If so, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `before` pseudo-element to achieve that:

**html**

```
<ul class="numeric">
<li>First
    <ul>
        <li>Indent </li>
        <li>Indent </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Second
    <ul>
        <li>Indent</li>
        <li>Indent</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Third
        <ul>
            <li>Indent</li>
            <li>Indent</li>
            <li>Indent</li>
            <li>Indent</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li>Fourth
    <ul>
        <li>Indent</li>
        <li>Indent</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Five</li>
```

**css**

```
ul.numeric { counter-reset:section; list-style-type:none; }
ul.numeric li { list-style-type:none; }
ul.numeric li ul { counter-reset:subsection; }
ul.numeric li:before{
    counter-increment:section;
    content:counter(section) ". ";
}
ul.numeric li ul li:before {
    counter-increment:subsection;
    content:counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4jbLr2b9/3/)

**References:**

[CSS counter-reset Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-reset.asp)

Comment: Is it supposed to work if I set the element.style by hand on each element? I tried and it does not work. Your example works using an external css file though.

Comment: Nope i didn't use an external css file.. I use pure css. See my fiddle example.

Comment: But [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tpqe74ov/) does not work.

Comment: of course it doesn't. My answer based using `:before` pseudo-element. Take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141374/using-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-with-inline-css

Comment: Can I use `:before` in an inline styling?

Comment: Nope.. Take a look in last link

Comment: You are welcome. You can achieve this if you use css i provide. Not inline of course :)