# Nested Numbered Lists Mixed With Alphabet & Roman Characters

Tags: html, list

May I know is it possible to create something like this :

```
1. Food
   1.1 Vege
       a. Carrot
          i. White Carrot
          ii. Red Carrot
   1.2 Meat
       a. Chicken
       b. beef
2. Beverages
```

I've seen many solution for mixed list with numbers and alphabets, but I can't make something like this which include number,nested number, alphabet, roman characters using simpler css code.

Refer to the solution on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3rtLw7q/) for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729927/number-nested-ordered-lists-in-html), it only able to create nested number, but without alphabet and roman characters.

Below is what I did (to fake the effect) :

```
.primary {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

}

/* Direct child under ol */
.primary>li {
  counter-increment: item;

}

/* Before direct child under ol */
.primary>li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    padding-right: 0.6em;    

}

.primary>li li {
    margin: 0px;

}

/* Before li of second level ol */
.primary>li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";

}

/* Third level ol */
.pri-inner {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
    padding-left:20px;
}

/* Hide the counter content on third level */
.pri-inner li:before {
    content:none;
    display:none;
}

/* Fourth level ol */
.pri-inner2{
    list-style-type: lower-roman;
    padding-left:25px;
}
```

The sample html code look like this

```
<ol class="primary">
  <li>First
    <ol class="primary">
      <li>Inside First</li>
      <li>
        <ol class="pri-inner">
          <li>Inside inside
            <ol class="pri-inner2">
              <li>Maximum inside</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>
```

So, is there any better way to achieve that? Because I have to hide the counter on 3rd level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`counter()` accepts a second parameter for the list type, i.e. `counter(item, lower-alpha)`

So the following CSS could do it, or could be tweaked to use your class names.

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: table;
    counter-increment: item;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li li {
    margin: 0;
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}

li li li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-alpha) ". ";
}

li li li li:before {
    content: counter(item, lower-roman) ". ";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eke4afd8/

Comment: Thanks so much !! It works like a charm through a little bit customization to my code ^_^ By the way, it's my very first time asking a question here.